# Script wont delete instantiate in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

i have a script that creates a clone over time and delete it but it will only spawn it

```
    public GameObject Obstycle;
public Transform NextSpawn;

public float MaxTimer = 3;
public float Timer = 0;

public void Update()
{
    if(Timer > MaxTimer)
    {
        GameObject newObject = Instantiate(Obstycle);
        Instantiate(Obstycle, NextSpawn);
        Destroy(newObject,3);
        Timer = 0;
    }
    Timer += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating your `Obstycle` twice:

```cs
GameObject newObject = Instantiate(Obstycle); // 1
Instantiate(Obstycle, NextSpawn); // 2
```

So when you destroy `newObject`, there's still an active instance. Either destroy both instances or only create a single instance:

```cs
GameObject newObject = Instantiate(Obstycle, NextSpawn);
Destroy(newObject,3);
Timer = 0;
```

or

```cs
GameObject newObject = Instantiate(Obstycle);
GameObject newObjectTwo = Instantiate(Obstycle, NextSpawn);
Destroy(newObject,3);
Destroy(newObjectTwo,3);
Timer = 0;
```